# Paypal references transaction issue

Tags: php, curl, paypal

I am really upset of the paypal support. i just going to integrate it using php curl.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-pro/integration-guide/reference-transactions/

I integrated it like this,

```
$postData = json_encode(array(

                    'USER' => 'developer-facilitator_api1.example.com',

                'PWD' => 'T2EZG7CVAPWRWER9SHZKK',

                'SIGNATURE' => 'An5ns1Kso7MWUdW4ErQKJJsdadaJ4qi4-APXpHmjsOPnzMnURUt4CdX1ua-BZ',

                    'VERSION' => '86',

                    'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION' => 'SALE',

                    'RETURNURL' => 'https://example.com/thank-you',

                    'CANCELURL' => 'https://texample.com',

                    'METHOD' => 'DoReferenceTransaction',

                    'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE' =>'USD',

                    'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT' => 1,

                ));
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp');
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,true);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$postData);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,true);
        $output = urldecode(curl_exec($ch));
        print_r($output);
```

when i run this it is showing the error like

```
   ACK=Failure&L_ERRORCODE0=81002&L_SHORTMESSAGE0=Unspecified Method&L_LONGMESSAGE0=Method Specified is not Supported&L_SEVERITYCODE0=Error

    I don't know where i did mistake.it is classic api of paypal. I am selecting this api because i want to receive payment from buyer account in future using transaction id. Is there any other method for future transaction from buyer account.
```

Actually i have service providing app (education). tutor and student interact in my app once the tutor provide class to student payment will be proceed without any dependence of student.

when the student select the payment method paypal in initial he/she will login his/her paypal account that time i just want to take some information like(transaction id) then when student take the class from tutor in future the payment will be proceed and deduct amount from his/her account because it is like online course so once the class is done, payment will be proceed.
Can anyone please help me to fix it out.

Answer (score 0):

Your PayPal Sandbox account developer-facilitator@example.com has not enabled the function of Reference Transaction. You have to contact PayPal technical support to enable this function and then this error issue can be solved.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you valuable time.